# How to get SKU code, Buyer Code and CSC in Android Studios

Tags: java, android, mobile, samsung-mobile

I'm developing an Android App and I need to be able to capture the SKU, Buyer Code and CSC of the device (only Samsung smartphones). I guess I only need the Buyer code (Country Code) and the CSC, but I've been searching and it looks like the SKU code already has these two codes.

I need these codes so I can restrict my App to some specific smartphones, specifically those that where bought in a specific country.

I can't find a way or a class that will help me get these information. I'm already capturing the device's IMEI and model, but not the Buyer Code or CSC.

I appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that post providing some Basic information.
[How to obtain Firmware version of Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421604/how-to-obtain-firmware-version-of-android-programmatically)

Some data like CSC are given by different ways depending on the manufacturer.

For Samsung for example, you will find information about software in **/system/SW_Configuration.xml** and about buyer in **/system/csc/sales_code.dat** and **/efs/imei/mps_code.dat**

Comment: Erratum ! On new Samsung models (SMG-950 - SMG-955, Galaxy S8 & S8+), the /system/SW_Configuration.xml doesn't exist anymore. AFAIK, there is no way to read CSC Value from Android