# How to obtain Firmware version of Android programmatically?

Tags: android, version, android-build, android-firmware

The following screenshot of a generic tablet shows an example of Firmware version:
[image]

We have tried pretty much everything of [Android Build](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html), none of them is the firmware version.

Answer (score 3):

Firmware is the operating software available on an Android device, and it is available in different versions designed by different manufacturers. Basically it's the device-specific part of the software. For example, you may have Android 4.2.2 running on your phone, but have a firmware number that looks completely different because it relates to more details than just Operating System. The firmware number consists of several elements, all of which are essential for the functioning of the phone:

PDA: Android operating system and your customizations.
Phone: the actual identifier of your device.
CSC (Country Exit Code): the languages and country-specific parameters.
Bootloader: the boot loader program that runs at startup to all unit processes.

> **Software Build Version** is basically the **Firmware Version**.

See `android.os.Build.VERSION`. SDK or SDK in contain the API version. `android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES` contains the relevant constants.

> `String deviceSoftwareVersion=telephonyManager.getDeviceSoftwareVersion();`

Refer to this [Build.VERSION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)

> Procedure to use it in code.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
     // only for gingerbread and newer versions
}
```

> This can be also checked by through code

```
System.out.println("button press on device name = "+android.os.Build.MODEL +" brand = "+android.os.Build.BRAND +" OS version = "+android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE + " SDK version = " +android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
```

> UPDATE

Try this one -

1. `android.os.Build.FINGERPRINT`
2. `android.os.Build.BOARD`
3. `Build.HOST`
4. `Build.ID`

> 5. `Build.SERIAL`

Check the following Code.

> **FINAL UPDATE**

```
String mString = "";

    mString.concat("VERSION.RELEASE {" + Build.VERSION.RELEASE + "}");
    mString.concat("\nVERSION.INCREMENTAL {" + Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL + "}");
    mString.concat("\nVERSION.SDK {" + Build.VERSION.SDK + "}");
    mString.concat("\nBOARD {" + Build.BOARD + "}");
    mString.concat("\nBRAND {" + Build.BRAND + "}");
    mString.concat("\nDEVICE {" + Build.DEVICE + "}");
    mString.concat("\nFINGERPRINT {" + Build.FINGERPRINT + "}");
    mString.concat("\nHOST {" + Build.HOST + "}");
    mString.concat("\nID {" + Build.ID + "}");

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(mString);
```

> You can also use`Build.DISPLAY`

A build ID string meant for displaying to the user

Comment: api version is.. not the same as firmware version

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I appreciate it. Unfortunately, none of the parameters you mentioned is the firmware version.  As I mentioned in my original post,  we have tried pretty much everything of Build including those you mentioned.

Comment: is there any official source of above answer ,

Answer (score 0):

I used following code to get firmware version of my device:

```
public String getFirmwareVersion() {
    try {
        Class cls = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
        Method method = cls.getMethod("get", String.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        return (String) method.invoke(cls, FIRMWARE_VERSION_PROPERTY);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As `FIRMWARE_VERSION_PROPERTY` I used `"ro.product.version"`
I've got this property address from the device manufacturer.

This address can vary for different devices and manufacturers, so it's advisable to contact manufacturer's tech support to get the correct one.